# RowMeans of DataFrame Excluding Some Columns

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
Leaf1 Leaf2 Leaf3 Root1 Root2 Root3 Shoot1 Shoot2 Shoot3
1 2 3 4 5 6 2 4 5 
46 22 33 44 11 33 22 44 33
100 22 2 33 2 222 2222 2113 2827
```

I would like to calculate the RowMeans of all of the rows, excluding each group as you move across the column (i.e; The new data frame would have three columns, either `Root`,`Shoot`, or `Leaf` and underneath that Column name would be the rowmeans of all columns not matching a given group name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may remove the suffix digits with `sub`, `split` the data into `list` of datasets, loop over the data and get the `rowMeans`

```
sapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\d+$", "", names(df1))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
       Leaf     Root       Shoot
[1,]  2.00000  5.00000    3.666667
[2,] 33.66667 29.33333   33.000000
[3,] 41.33333 85.66667 2387.333333
```

---

If it needs to exclude those columns,

```
sapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\d+$", "", names(df1))), \(x) 
    rowMeans(df1[setdiff(names(df1), names(x))], na.rm = TRUE))
            Leaf        Root Shoot
[1,]    4.333333    2.833333   3.5
[2,]   31.166667   33.333333  31.5
[3,] 1236.500000 1214.333333  63.5
```

Or we loop over the unique names and exclude by matching with `grep`

```
sapply(unique(sub("\\d+$", "", names(df1))), \(nm)
   rowMeans(df1[grep(nm, names(df1), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE))
            Leaf        Root Shoot
[1,]    4.333333    2.833333   3.5
[2,]   31.166667   33.333333  31.5
[3,] 1236.500000 1214.333333  63.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Leaf1 = c(1L, 46L, 100L), Leaf2 = c(2L, 22L, 22L
), Leaf3 = c(3L, 33L, 2L), Root1 = c(4L, 44L, 33L), Root2 = c(5L, 
11L, 2L), Root3 = c(6L, 33L, 222L), Shoot1 = c(2L, 22L, 2222L
), Shoot2 = c(4L, 44L, 2113L), Shoot3 = c(5L, 33L, 2827L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```